# How to get the dbId to use fitToView() in Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I want to display a 2D sheet with Forge Viewer and zoom in on a specific string (in this case, a room name) in the sheet.
I know that Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D.fitToView(dbIds) method can be used, but how can I get the dbId for the target string such as room name?

I tried checking with getProperties(), getBulkProperties() and search() of GuiViewer3D, but fitToView() did not work as expected.

Comment: so, you have got the dbId and checked with these methods of getProperties etc? Can this text string be selected manually in viewer? If yes, please call viewer.getSelection() it it tells a dbId. If you still have the issue, please share us a copy sheet and highlight which text string you want to fit to. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Yes, I called viewer.getSelection() and then getProperties. However, the string displayed was not included in response.

I set up a "color scheme" for a room in the Revit application and now I can search by room name.
Having achieved my objective, I will close my question.
Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: thank you much for sharing the experience! I did not realize it is  related with Revit  Room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found that by setting up a "color scheme" for a room in the Revit application, we can search object by room name.

1. Setting up a "color scheme" for a room in the Revit application.
2. Call search() with the room name to get the dbId.
3. Call fitToView() with the dbId.